# PercentForm in SetterBar Labels

Tags: style, user-interface

I want to have the numbers that a `SetterBar` displays for the user to select to appear as percentages. For example, the following code should have percentages not only in the output but also in the buttons for the setter bar:

```
Manipulate[
 Style["Percentage is " <> ToString@PercentForm@x, 
  FontFamily -> "Georgia"],
 {{x, .02, "Percentage:"}, Range[.01, .05, .01], 
  ControlType -> SetterBar, Background -> GrayLevel[.8], 
  Appearance -> "Row"}]
```

In other words, the white selected button and the gray unselected buttons should all be in the form of 1%, 2%, 3%, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs list the control form `{u,{u1->lbl1,u2->lbl2,...}}` for the setter bar, so just use `Rule[#, PercentForm[#]] & /@ Range[.01, .05, .01]` instead of `Range[.01, .05, .01]`.

Comment: Many thanks. I had tried `{#->PercentForm@#}&/@...` but it would not work, I should have tried `Rule[ ]...`; it turns out `(#->PercentForm#)&/@...` also works.